# ASP.NET Identity with Entity Framework seeding the database issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm using Identity with framework entity.
I'm trying to seed my database with some data - 1 user, and 1 role.

The role is getting seeded properly and everything is good.

**The user is not getting seeded - the issue.**

**Program.cs file**

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
            var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
            var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<AppRole>>();
            await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
            await Roles.RoleInitalizer(roleManager);
            await Seed.SeedUsers(userManager);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during migration");
        }

        await host.RunAsync();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**Roles.cs file - works as intended**

```
public class Roles
{
    public static async Task RoleInitalizer(RoleManager<AppRole> roleManager)
    {
        var roles = new List<AppRole>
        {
            new AppRole{Name="User"}
        };
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
        }
    }
}
```

**The seed.cs file - user seeding - the issue is here**

```
    public class Seed
{
    public static async Task SeedUsers(UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
    {
        if (await userManager.Users.AnyAsync()) return;

        var userData = await System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync("Data/Seed/UserSeedData.json");
        var users = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<AppUser>>(userData);
        if (users == null) return;

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            user.UserName = user.UserName.ToLower();
            await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "@Test123456789");
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");
        }

    }
}
```

**AppUser.cs File**

```
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Hero> Heroes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AppUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**ConfigureService from startup.cs**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddAplicationServices(_config);

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services.AddCors();

        services.AddIdentityServices(_config);
    }
```

**AddAplicationServices Function from startup**

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAplicationServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IHeroRepository, HeroRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfiles).Assembly);

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);


        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        });


        return services;
    }
```

**AddIdentityServices function from startup.cs**

```
public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(opt =>
        {
            opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        })
            .AddRoles<AppRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<AppRole>>()
            .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>()
            .AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<AppRole>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

        // services.TryAddSingleton<ISystemClock, SystemClock>();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = "yad2",
                    ValidIssuer = "yad",

                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"])),
                };
            });


        services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
        {
            opt.AddPolicy("RequireUserRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("User"));
        });

        return services;
    }
```

**The UserSeedData.json file**

```
[
{
    "UserName": "Test",
    "Email": "test@test.com"
}
]
```

[Here is the project stracture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/079T6.png)

**This is the project from GitHub just in case**
https://github.com/davidax0204/proj

I'm not able to figure out why the roles getting seeded properly and the user is not.
I double-checked that the seeding file has the correct structure as the table of the app user.

I'm getting dropping the old database and starting the project again and only the role is getting seeded every time.

I have tried to manipulate the Seed file but nothing seems to work for me.

Can someone please explain to me why that issue happens so I can learn from my mistakes?

And how can I solve that issue?

Comment: Could you paste snippet of `AppUser.cs`?

Comment: Step through your code and inspect your variables. Where does it end up? What database is you UserManager writing to? What does your Startup look like?

Comment: @kosist I have updated my question below

Comment: @CodeCaster I have updated my question below

Comment: I guess issue is in JSON parsing. It has keys "UserName" and "Email", while AppUser has completely different fields. Are you sure that `var userData = await System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync("Data/Seed/UserSeedData.json");
        var users = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<AppUser>>(userData);` this line returns list of users?

Comment: @kosist Hi! AppUser is of type IdentityUser therefore he has UserName and Email properties.
How can I make sure if those lines actually return a value? sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @kosist I checked now im pretty sure that the System.IO.File.ReadAllTextAsync("Data/Seed/UserSeedData.json");         var users = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<AppUser>>(userData); 
return null. but im not getting why

Comment: @David, make sure that `UserSeedData.json` file contains data when application is executed. Be aware, that when you run code, file should be located in `bin\Debug\` folder. So make sure that file is not empty there.